# Run .jar file from browser in macOS

Tags: java, windows, macos, registry, plist

I did a Java application that is launched by a key stored in the Windows registry. So, when i digit the key on the browser, it runs my application.

Key:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Decoder]
@="URL:Decoder Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Decoder\Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Decoder\Shell\Open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Decoder\Shell\Open\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_73\\bin\\javaw.exe -jar \"C:\\Decoder\\dist\\Decoder.jar\" \"%1\""
```

Now i want to make my application run in macOS system but i can't because macOS doesn't have a registry like Windows.

I already tought about a way to do it and the only ideas I had are:

1. Create a Safari plug-in that is activated when I type a specific word;
2. I found on Internet a discussion about plist files on macOS but i don't know how they work.

Is there a way to run my file through macOs browser?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It works, thanks Jay!

Comment: I think you should probably close this question...